# MoM changes in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to do month over month salary changes based on last 2 months and grouping this by unique id?How do I go about this issue? Thank you.

I tried this

```
SELECT 
    employee_id, 
    fiscal_year, 
    salary,
    LAG(salary) OVER (
        PARTITION BY employee_id 
        ORDER BY fiscal_year) previous_salary
FROM
    basic_pays

where  
date between Dateadd(month,-2,_date) And Getdate()
```

but it's bringing back 0 for all and runs a very long time.

Comment: Is that `;` after `basic_pays` a typo?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Yes, edited it. Microsoft sql server

Comment: Do you have a column named _date and date? Null values can come back for previous_salary but the only way a zero would come back is if it is somewhere in your data. I would doublecheck records where the salary equals 0 and see if there is something out of sorts there.